# VSCode with ms-python: debugger not stopping on breakpoints?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've got a very simple Python program:

```
print("Hello")
print("Hello")
print("Hello")
print("Hello")
print("Hello")
print("Hello")
```

I place break points on every single line in the program, then pull up the Debug Activity Bar in Visual Studio Code.  I click the 'Start Debugging' button, and I see all the output from the program appear in the 'Terminal' tab.

I haven't been successful in getting the program to stop.

I tried doing the File > Open Folder menu option in order to work in a new workspace (I think?  Is this the right work for it?  A new VSCode environment, for sure) and it now works great on that simple file, in that new folder.  It's clearly a problem with my configuration in the other project.

There's definitely a problem with my virtual environment configuration - when I remove the python.pythonPath variable from my settings.json file this all works fine.

My WorkSpace Settings file contains only the path to Python.exe in the virtual environment. Commenting this line out makes the problem go away (my-python hits breakpoints and steps through code just fine), putting this line back in prevents the debugger from hitting breakpoints / stepping through code.

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "E:\\Work\\Student_Work\\BIT_143_New\\NUnit_Autograders\\Autograder-py\\Scripts\\python.exe",
}
```

**I would greatly appreciate any advice on how to troubleshoot this problem, wherein a misconfigured virtual environment is preventing the Python debugger from working!**

Comment: I just tested your code and it terminated fine for me. Have you tried uninstalling and re-installing the extension?

Comment: I think the problem is being caused by the virtual environment that I created (it works great when using my system-wide Python).   I'm not quite sure what the next step is, but I'm thinking "repo using a brand-new venv and a trivial Python file, then log it as an issue" :)

Comment: If you can come up with a reproducing setup, please file an issue.